# How to loop through array and use the values in the next request (each time with different value) - postman

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, postman

My response inculde an array. I need to use each time different id number in the
**next** req.
For exp.. if my first response is:

```
{
  "params": {
    "Deposits": [
      {
        "id": "23",
        "name": "blue"
      },
      {
        "id": "54",
        "name": "pink"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to take at first the value of the first deposit' id (which is 23)
and implement it in my next req, run it, and then run it again but this time with the next
id value (which is 54)

I've tried to use a 'for' loop in my first request 'test'

```
const responseJson = pm.response.json();
var Products = responseJson.params.Deposits;
for (var i=0; i<Products.length; i++)
{
 postman.setEnvironmentVariable(Products[i].id)
}
```

and in my second request body i used

```
{
"id": "{{Id}}"  // neither{{Products[i].id}} worked. At first should be eql to 23 and then 54
"Amount": 2
"date" : null
}
```

But...its not working. Im missing something..
How do i use the different id's values in the next req?

*****Edited:*****
My collection has a total of 4 requests.
The flow is:

1. Running the first req and reciving in the response the DEPOSITS array, each one with a uniqe *id*.
2. Running the second request, with the
   **first** id from the array that I received in the first response.
3. Running the 3rd and then 4th request (there's no "id" that i need to implement there, just to run it with some different info of the choosen deposit..)
4. Go back to the *2nd* request, change to the next id number from the array, and move on again to the 3rd and then to the 4th request

So It's basically running request 1 > 2> 3> 4 > 2> 3> 4> 2 > 3 >4 >2...
and each time a different deposit is choosen.

Comment: Do you want run this flow automatically based on the number of `ids`?

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE:

support flow `1 > 2> 3> 4 > 2> 3> 4> 2 > 3 >4 >2...`  when using Postman runner.

**Request 1**: get array of `ids`

Tab `Test`

```
const res = pm.response.json();
const ids = _.pluck(res.params.Deposits, 'id');
pm.environment.set('ids', JSON.stringify(ids));
```

**Request 2**: get `id` from `ids`

Tab `Pre-request`

```
const ids = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('ids'));
pm.environment.set('id', ids.shift());
pm.environment.set('ids', JSON.stringify(ids));
```

Tab `Body`

```
{
  "id": "{{id}}",
  "Amount": 2,
  "date": null
}
```

**Request 3**: nothing

**Request 4**: add logic, if running out of `ids`, stop flow. Else, continue with request 2.

```
const ids = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('ids'));

if (ids.length === 0) {
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
} else {
    postman.setNextRequest("Req2")
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Anything else that I need to add to the pre-request?
cause im getting 'JSONError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0'

Comment: @Hila please double check your script. I've tested these on my side, no error at all.

Comment: you r right! sorry!   And if i want to take it one step further.. if i have a *third* request that i need to run with the first id.. and only then(!) go back to the second to change to the second id?

Comment: Please, edit your question and clear out what you want. You can add examples and flow you’re doing.

Comment: Thank u! (i was sick..sorry for the delay). Ill check if its working for me later on the week